# Custom Form Template Issues WSS

Tags: custom-form, rendering-template, wss-3.0

This is mainly a verification question as I have been fighting with an issue for a couple of days now. I have two lists derived from 2 custom content types. Both content types used the task base content type. Each of the derived content types have custom form rendering templates. I am using a custom usercontrol with codebehind added to the .ascx page as a control to redraw the forms differently. One of these forms renders without issue and the rendering template loads along with my control. The other list and its template will not load following the exact procedure as the first one. What I mean is that the link will carry you to the newform.aspx page and it will load the listform webpart as I can see it when I view source. It is just not loading the template I asked it to load just like I did on the other form. I am wondering if it is because both lists share the same type number (107) or if it might be something else. So does each list need to have a custom type number or does that not really matter? I ask because I can change the content type of the nonworking one to use the same template as the working one and it will load just fine.

UPDATE: I tried changing the type and even changed the content type and redeployed the entire solution. There is no error message but it does not load the rendering template from the controltemplates folder. I can see that it is there and I can see that the content type should be loading it, but it does not. The other one as I said laods and works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when everything looks like it should work and it does not then there is something else going on. It turns out that in my case, my solution was corrupted somehow. I restored from a recent backup and then added the rendering template back and it worked just fine. Feel free to delete or keep this in case someone else has the same issue.